# Regex capture group swift

Tags: ios, regex, swift, swift2

I have a regex search method in string:

```
extension String {
    func searchRegex (regex: String) -> Array<String> {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions(rawValue: 0))
            let nsstr = self as NSString
            let all = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsstr.length)
            var matches : Array<String> = Array<String>()
            regex.enumerateMatchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: all) {
                (result : NSTextCheckingResult?, _, _) in
                let theResult = nsstr.substringWithRange(result!.range)
                matches.append(theResult)
            }
            return matches
        } catch {
            return Array<String>()
        }
    }
}
```

It works good. But if i have a regular expression `product_title:\['(.*)'` it returns me `product_title:[\'Some title bla bla\'` but i only need the part `(.*)`.

I'm new in swift, but in python this problem solved by using `groups()` function. How to use capture group in swift. Please give me example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSTextCheckingResult` has a `numberOfRanges` property and a `rangeAtIndex()` method that lets you grab the range for individual capture groups. So if you wanted the first capture group instead of the whole matched string, you would modify your code to:

```
        var matches : Array<String> = Array<String>()
        regex.enumerateMatchesInString(self, options: NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: all) {(result : NSTextCheckingResult?, _, _) in
            let capturedRange = result!.rangeAtIndex(1)
            if !NSEqualRanges(capturedRange, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)) {
                let theResult = nsstr.substringWithRange(result!.rangeAtIndex(1))
                matches.append(theResult)
            }
        }
```

Comment: I got a NSRangeException when using this with more than one capture group.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35415678/why-does-having-more-than-one-capture-group-in-my-regex-crash-my-app/35415787?noredirect=1#35415787