# Retrieve string between two special characters

Tags: regex, swift

I have an image URL which I need to extract the UUID from. The URL is formed like so:

```
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-6312172760840445565.appspot.com/o/images%2Fjohn%2F356BEDA3-E0B2-4659-9DE2-37FC8C13CDF7.webp?alt=media&token=f0c16de2-c1d9-4392-8f5b-9aa5c0527ea3"
```

This URL points to the image in my bucket, where its name format is `/images/[username]/[UUID]`. I need to obtain this UUID in order to delete it so it doesn't take up space when the user uploads a new image (which replaces the existing one).

I tried testing this [here](https://regex101.com/r/iH9uS8/10) with the following regex: `\%([A-Z0-9-]+)\.` Essentially, I want to extract all the text between a `%2F` and a period (`.`), which is where the UUID is (`356BEDA3-E0B2-4659-9DE2-37FC8C13CDF7`). It successfully matched the pattern I wanted (under "match information")...well, including the `2F` which is actually an escaped slash.

However, when using it in Swift, **it's actually matching the characters including and after the first `%`** (output is `%2Fj`). I've tried this:

```
let regex = Regex("%([A-Z0-9-]+).")

if let match = regex.match(self.existingItem.photoURL) {
    print(match.matchedString)
}
```

Side note: I'm using [this](https://github.com/sharplet/Regex) Regex framework.

Can anyone please shed some insight on why this happens in Swift and how to fix it?

Comment: @rock321987 You are right, you should make an answer with your solution.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew has already answered..no need to add redundancy

Comment: @rock321987 For people wondering, escaping actually requires two slashes (`\\.`) in Swift. I tried with one but that gives a compiler error.

Comment: That is exactly the reason why I suggest `[.]` - looks tidier.

Comment: yup..that was obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the **Capture**:

```
let reg = Regex("%2F([A-Z0-9-]+)[.]")

if let res = reg.match(self.existingItem.photoURL)?.captures[0] {
  print("\(res)")
}
```

Note that the `(...)` creates a *capture group* that is used to get smaller substrings from your matches.

Judging by the [Sharplet Regex Github page](https://github.com/sharplet/Regex), capture group indexing starts with `0`, so the first capture group can be accessed via `0` index.

Comment: Just FYI: I used `[.]` to match a dot, but you can escape it as `\\.` - `let reg = Regex("%([A-Z0-9-]+)\\.")
`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! My regex is now actually `%2F([A-Z0-9-]+)\\.` because I need it to match (and ignore) the `2F` which is actually an escaped slash.

Comment: You really do not have to escape the dot if you place it into a character class. Here is a link to [**Baskslash hell** article](https://tudorbarbu.ninja/backslash-hell/). It is about PHP, but in fact, when you can avoid backslashing, I'd rather go for it.

Answer (score 1):

@rock321987 is right, you've got to escape the dot:

```
%([A-Z0-9-]+)\\.
```

FWIW, it works like this without using a third-party framework:

```
if let range = text.rangeOfString("%([A-Z0-9-]+)\\.", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
    let match = text.substringWithRange(range)
    print(match)
}
```

Prints:

> %2F356BEDA3-E0B2-4659-9DE2-37FC8C13CDF7.

Comment: Your regex is identical to mine, and you are not using the framework OP uses.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ? I've made my own answer in a Playground, thank you. If anything, I was inspired by rock321987's comment - and I gave him attribution. As for the framework, I'm explicitly telling in my answer that it's a version *without* using a third-party framework, for information.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Native Swift alternatives are always valuable additions to framework-specific questions, so this answer stands on its own, even if the regex:es are the same (this one is answered just shortly after yours). On another point: is `.captures[0]` as specified in your answer (which is also given as an example by the Sharplet Regex github page) really safe? I.e., are we certain that the string array `.captures` (`[String?]`) is always non-empty? Instead of `.captures[0]`, possibly `.captures.first` would be a more appropriate choice in the `if let ...` clause.

Comment: @dfri: If the question were about getting a submatch from a match, I'd close it as a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290955/regex-capture-group-swift) question. If `.captures.first` is more appropriate, use it, I only provided an example.

Comment: @dfri The documentation states this: "Note: Usually if the match was successful, the captures will by definition be non-nil. However if a given capture group is optional, the captured string may also be nil, depending on the particular string that is being matched against." That is why I use an `if let match = ...` so if it's nil, it won't even execute the captures part.

Comment: @wreckingcode I see. As long as the captured group (`.captures` array) is non-empty, explicit subscript access should be safe, but I would still recommend `.first` rather than `[0]` (the former returning `nil` in case of an empty array, whereas the latter yields a runtime exception in case of an empty array).