# How to use an array in an if statement

Tags: arrays, swift, if-statement

I am writing the following code including two `if statements` in `swift 5`, where I am splitting a sentence into an array including words and punctuations ([How to split a sentence into words as well as punctuations and spaces? [Swift]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72471047/how-to-split-a-sentence-into-words-as-well-as-punctuations-and-spaces-swift)).

As I use `similar if statements` a lot, it is getting annoying to modify one by one. Is there any way I can make it easier to modify if necessary? (for example by using an array)

The array I am thinking about looks as follows (please pretend that this includes the same characters in the first and the second if-statements in the code..):

```
let characterToStartNewWord: [String] = [" ","(",")","-", "—", "`", "‘", "/", "*","”", "[", "]", "—", "“", ":", ";", "!", "?"]
```

**code**

```
func sentenceSplitter(text_input: String) ->  [String]  {
        // delete "- "
        let text: String = text_input.replacingOccurrences(of: "- ", with: "")
        
        var list = [String]()
        let characterToStartNewWord: [String] = [" ","(",")","-", "—", "`", "‘", "/", "*","”", "[", "]", "—", "“"]
        
        
        var currentSubString = "";
        text.enumerateSubstrings(in: text.startIndex..<text.endIndex, options: String.EnumerationOptions.byComposedCharacterSequences) { (substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, value) in
            if let _subString = substring {
                if (!currentSubString.isEmpty &&
                    (_subString.compare(" ") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare(",") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare(".") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare(";") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("!") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("?") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare(":") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("(") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare(")") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("-") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("“") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("*") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("/") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("[") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("]") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("—") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("‘") == .orderedSame
                     || _subString.compare("`") == .orderedSame
                    )
                ) {
                    //create word if see any of those character and currentSubString is not empty
                    list.append(currentSubString)
                    if _subString == " " {
                        list.append(_subString)
                    }
                    currentSubString = _subString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
                    
                    
                    characterToStartNewWord.forEach{
                        if _subString == $0 && _subString != " " {
                            list.append(_subString)
                            currentSubString = currentSubString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: $0))
                        }
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    if (
                        
                        _subString.compare(" ") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("(") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare(")") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("-") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("*") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("”") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("—") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("`") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("‘") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("/") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("[") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("]") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("—") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("‘") != .orderedSame &&
                        _subString.compare("`") != .orderedSame)
                    {
                        currentSubString += _subString
                    } else {
                        
                        characterToStartNewWord.forEach{
                            if _subString == $0 {
                                list.append(_subString)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        //last word
        if (!currentSubString.isEmpty) {
            list.append(currentSubString)
        }
        
        
        return list
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use an array. You can simply use a string (collection of characters) to initialize a set and check if it contains or not a character:

```
let characters = Set(#",;:!?()-*”—`‘/[]—"#)
if characters.contains(char) {
    // code
}
```

If you just need to check if a string starts or not with one of those characters:

```
let string = "[Test]"
if let first = string.first, characters.contains(first) {
    print(true)
}
```

---

edit/update:

In your case (I have not tested the code below):

```
func sentenceSplitter(text_input: String) ->  [String]  {
    let text = text_input.replacingOccurrences(of: "- ", with: "")
    var list = [String]()
    let characterToStartNewWord = Set(#" ()-—`‘/*”[]—"#)
    var currentSubString = ""
    text.enumerateSubstrings(
        in: text.startIndex...,
        options: .byComposedCharacterSequences
    ) { substring, substringRange, enclosingRange, stop in
        if let subString = substring {
            if currentSubString.count == 1,
               characterToStartNewWord.contains(subString[subString.startIndex]) {
                list.append(currentSubString)
                if subString == " " { list.append(subString) }
                currentSubString = subString.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                characterToStartNewWord.forEach {
                    if subString == String($0),
                       subString != " " {
                        list.append(subString)
                        currentSubString = currentSubString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: String($0)))
                    }
                }
            } else {
                let charSet = Set(" ()-*”—‘/[]—`")
                if subString.count == 1, !charSet.contains(subString[subString.startIndex]) {
                    currentSubString += subString
                } else {
                    characterToStartNewWord.forEach {
                        if subString == String($0) {
                            list.append(subString)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Leo Dabus. I tried your code and I got an error saying that `Type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') has no member 'orderedSame'`. I may have needed to explain the entire code. I added that to my question.

Comment: @user8460166 Not sure why would you need `orderedSame` using the code above.

Comment: @user8460166 check my last edit.

Comment: Thank you, @Leo Dabus. I appreciate you taking time for me to update the code! I tried and something is not working right... now the " " (space) after a word is somehow added in `list` at the point before the word... I am currently trying to figure out why this is happening. I did not include the `return` part before in the entire code, so I added. and `.startIndex` is totally new to me, so I am learning about it.